# postgresql query to show the groups of a user

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I create a user in a group, like:

```
create role user_1 login inherit in role group_1;
```

later, with which query could I retrieve to which group(s) a user belongs to?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check pg_roles, [pg_authid](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-authid.html) and pg_auth_members to get the details about roles.

Comment: I was just answering with a link to pg_auth_members too!

Answer (score 75):

Just to give a copy&pastable solution - On PostgreSQL (tested 8.4 and 9.3) you can do:

```
select rolname from pg_user
join pg_auth_members on (pg_user.usesysid=pg_auth_members.member)
join pg_roles on (pg_roles.oid=pg_auth_members.roleid)
where
pg_user.usename='USERNAME';
```

where USERNAME is the name of the login role you are interested in.

Answer (score 25):

From the psql command line:

```
\dg
```

or

```
\du
```

Comment: Command line for the win! I cant find a good client app to replicate this with ease. Big downside of DataGrip IMHO.